# Uber REST API request receipt sandbox currency

Tags: uber-api

When I try to request a receipt for a ride in sandbox, the response seems to always come back as 9 USD. The amount I don't care too much about, but the currency is problematic. The request is made through the API (sandbox), and both estimate and actual ride request return the fare amounts in the local currency which might or might not be USD. Is there way to get the receipt also in local currency?

And is this just an omission in the sandbox implementation or will the receipt also be in USD in production API? The documentation does not mention any parameters for the receipt endpoint other than the request id (https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/requests-request_id-receipt-get)

I'm testing with API version v1.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, definitely seems like the sandbox receipt is just not working properly. When I do a request live and then fetch the receipt for the request after ride has completed, I will get the excepted local currency also on the receipt.

Answer (score 2):

Well, apparently from the site you provided, the currency is automatically adjusted to the location:

> **Currency**
>
> Currency is returned as the local currency of a given latitude & longitude. A fare estimate in San Francisco will be given in USD, while a fare estimate in Paris will be displayed in EUR. We also provide the ISO 4217 currency code for your own conversions.

I'm referring to https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/guides/localization.

Comment: For the estimates and ride request that is indeed true. But sandbox receipt is returned in USD. This is problem because now I have fare's returned in one currency and receipt for the same fare in another (USD).